# Property baseName unknown in build.gradle

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, jar

I have a spring-boot project with the following build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'regular-ghost-player'
version ''

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

task createJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Ghost Project',
            'Implementation-Version': version,
            'Main-Class': 'myCode.GhostSkeleton'
}
baseName = 'winnerBot' //Replace 'your_team_name' with your actual team name. No spaces allowed!
destinationDirectory.set(file("$projectDir/"))
from { configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
with jar
}
```

When I executed build gradle, I received this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\kongz\OneDrive\Desktop\BHCC-CS\2023SU CSC-239\wk9\regular-ghost-player\build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'regular-ghost-player'.
> Could not set unknown property 'baseName' for task ':createJar' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.
```

My jdk version is 17 and my gradle version is 8.0.2

I tried to upgrade gradle to the latest version 8.2.1. But it didn't work.

Comment: Fix your indentation and your problem should become obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Property `baseName` has been deprecated from gradle version 5, and has been removed from latest versions : https://docs.gradle.org/5.2.1/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar:baseName

please check API documentation and choose the correct property depending on what you need:  https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html

(maybe  https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar:archiveBaseName  ? )

Comment: Thank you so much. Appreciate it. That's helpful. The code works.